# watson speech to text degraded accuracy in continuous mode

Tags: speech-to-text

In a sample 1 minute audio clip of clear, good quality audio, I am seeing some strange transcription accuracy behaviour.

Accuracy is as expected for the first 45 seconds or so then all I get is a couple of stray words from the last 15 seconds.  The audio is still clear and understandable.

BUT... If I clip those last 15 seconds and send it by itself it is transcribed accurately...  so what the heck is going on here?  is the context of the full clip somehow messing it up?

```js
{
   "created": "2017-07-28T11:53:29.584Z",
   "id": "5f5f9f00-738b-11e7-8e0f-f3176d375982",
   "updated": "2017-07-28T11:54:03.398Z",
   "results": [{
      "result_index": 0,
      "results": [
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "everybody's good to see so many folks in chambers today we never know who's going to join us so welcome I'm city councillor Marianne lead ward and I am %HESITATION the chair of today's committee of the whole %HESITATION first I will read a safety notice which I think is gonna be on your screens as well it there is %HESITATION in the event of an emergency please evacuate council chambers by the narrow staircase which is located through the doorway marked exit and obey all instructions given by the clerk ",
               "confidence": 0.848
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "if assistance is required please see the clerk and once you've evacuated the building please gather in civic square outside of city hall ",
               "confidence": 0.948
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "so I would like to thank the media who is here with us today %HESITATION in person and the public for attending and remind ",
               "confidence": 0.959
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "person ",
               "confidence": 0.608
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "the proceedings on ",
               "confidence": 0.878
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "and they are also archived ",
               "confidence": 0.675
            }]
         }
      ]
   }],
   "status": "completed"
}
```

```js
{
   "created": "2017-07-28T11:58:25.384Z",
   "id": "0faf1e80-738c-11e7-8e0f-f3176d375982",
   "updated": "2017-07-28T11:58:32.559Z",
   "results": [{
      "result_index": 0,
      "results": [
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "US today are in person and the public for attending and remind everyone that if you can't be with us out in person you can catch ",
               "confidence": 0.945
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "the proceedings on live webcast ",
               "confidence": 0.859
            }]
         },
         {
            "final": true,
            "alternatives": [{
               "transcript": "and they are also archive ",
               "confidence": 0.731
            }]
         }
      ]
   }],
   "status": "completed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say what is going on without actually looking at the audio stream, can you please share that audio file with us through Bluemix customer support?   https://support.eu-gb.bluemix.net/gethelp/  we will take a look at it.